# Large Title Navigation Bar Overlaps when switching tabs

Tags: swift, scrollview, tabbar

Using a navigation controller in a tab bar controller the large title glitches when switching tabs.

[image]
[image]
[image]

SceneDelegate.swift

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController()), UIViewController()]

        window.rootViewController = tabBarController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

    self.title = "Main"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1400))
    contentView.backgroundColor = .gray
    self.scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

    scrollView.contentSize.height = 1700
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Scroll down until the large title collapses into the small title
- Switch to the second tab
- Switch back to the first tab
- Result: The scroll view is still scrolled down but the large title now overlaps the content. When scrolling a little bit, it snaps back to the small title.

This does not happen when it’s a table or collection view instead of the scroll view.

This started happening in iOS 13. Did I miss some change in the behavior or is this a bug? Does someone know a workaround?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure out how to fix it ?

Comment: Yes. Basically you have to set contentSize's height AND width. Without setting the width it will not work. Was a dumb mistake.